# Encrypting searchable fields in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I've come into a client requirement that I've to encrypt fields first_name, last_name, phone_number, username in a large database for confidentiality.

But if I encrypt those fields using PHP function I'm unable to perform SQL select (`LIKE , =`) search on those data. Is it possible to use `AES_ENCRYPT` without much performance loss, or any other fast way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this encryption need to happen in PHP? Look into *encryption at rest* solutions for MySQL, which basically encrypt the data stored on disk, but are transparent to your PHP code.

Comment: what we need is to prevent someone who have sql password should not read those values by running mysql command line, phpmyadmin or adminer any similar tool.

Comment: Sounds rather an issue that should be solved with appropriate access permissions to the database. But then again, I don't know your exact situation. Only that encryption always has searchability as a tradeoff…

Comment: Can we prevent mysql root on particular database?

Comment: @tan Yes you can restrict user access upto table level.

Comment: Well, create a root password which you *don't* give out willy nilly, and create more limited accounts with limited permissions and give those out to people as appropriate…

Comment: What I normally do in such situations is that Create users with limited access rules; and disallow access to certain tables, for eg: customer (which contain leads data), etc

Comment: In my case user root in wrong hands. The solution might work is to remove root user from my database say "project_db". Then create a new user "project_user" give has access to this database. But I was thinking that root will able to regain the permission to "project_db" himself.

Comment: Change root's password to something secret. Anybody that currently has `root` access will lose it. Give those users a new, limited account instead.

Comment: You could retrieve all the data from the individual users in the different tables via PHP script, then in that PHP script, encrypt the data with an encryption method of your choice, and then update the fields in the database with the encrypted value. You will however have to store a key that you will need for decryption of the data if you wish to display it on a user-level again. However, this might not be what you need in the end if you are able to make use of what some of the other comments suggest. And as you noted, using this will hinge some of your functionality, such as seach where like

Comment: Practical Techniques for Searches on Encrypted Data https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dawnsong/papers/se.pdf.. Basiclly create a search index table with encrypted keywords (can also be single character or number) that are present in the encrypted search document and positions which you also encrypt.. Only problem with this approach you need to update the search index if anny of those fields changes or more data is added

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [CipherSweet](https://github.com/paragonie/ciphersweet), which provides secure [authenticated encryption](https://tonyarcieri.com/all-the-crypto-code-youve-ever-written-is-probably-broken), key separation, and encrypted search in PHP (for use with SQL databases).

CipherSweet doesn't use MySQL's `AES_ENCRYPT()` function. In fact, you don't ever want to rely on MySQL's `AES_ENCRYPT()` function if the purpose of encrypting data is to hide it from the database server as a defense-in-depth strategy.

Instead, CipherSweet supports two back-ends out of the box:

- **FIPSCrypto** which only uses the algorithms approved for use in FIPS 140-2 certified applications (AES, SHA2, PBKDF2, HMAC, etc.)
- **ModernCrypto** which uses [libsodium](https://download.libsodium.org/doc) (which is faster and more secure, but less compatible with incumbent systems that only have OpenSSL).

With CipherSweet, you don't get `LIKE` or regex support. Instead, it uses a strategy called [blind indexing](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/05/building-searchable-encrypted-databases-with-php-and-sql) (which is analogous to how the `LIKE` operator is often used).